# Rails 3 Collection `sum` fails with TypeError

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a sample Rails 3.2.8 app (on Ruby 1.9.3) there is the following simple setup:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items

  def subtotal
    line_items.sum(&:price)
  end
end

class Line_Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  def price
    product.price * time
  end
end


account = Account.new

account.line_items.build do |item|
  item.years = 4
  item.product = Product.last
end

account.subtotal
#=> TypeError: nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal
```

As above the `subtotal` method fails with a conversion error. In `subtotal` I checked the type returned by `line_items.class` and got `Array`. If I update the definition of `subtotal` to either of the following, the method works:

```
line_items.to_a.sum(&:price)
#=> #<BigDecimal:7ff4d34ca7c8,'0.0',9(36)>

line_items.map(&:price).sum
#=> #<BigDecimal:7ff4d3373b40,'0.0',9(36)>
```

Why does the initial definition of `line_items.sum(&:price)` fail?

Comment: whats the type (class) returned by price? line_items[0].price.class ?

Comment: Weird. I run 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.1, but it works fine. Are you sure all records are returning the same class? Maybe loop over the price and check each class.

Comment: There was only one item in the collection when I was testing.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Rails (at least in 3.2.8).

In Rails 3.2.8, the `has_many` association is dynamically defining [`collection.sum`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/959fb8ea651fa6638aaa7caced20d921ca2ea5c1/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L181).
Though this isn't reflected in [A Guide to Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-association)
or [ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html); it is briefly listed in the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) under the "*Collection associations (one-to-many / many-to-many)*"
chart, but not referenced again.

According to the [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/959fb8ea651fa6638aaa7caced20d921ca2ea5c1/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L181), it will always try to hit the database using a SQL `sum`.
However, in this particular instance, the model isn't saved. So there's nothing
in the database.

So to clear that up a little:

```
account.line_items.sum(&:price)      # Uses Collection#sum, goes to database
account.line_items.map.sum(&:price)  # Uses Enumerable#map then Enumerable#sum
```

This has been logged under [issue #7928](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7928); which appears related to [issue #5215: "finders and scopes on has_many association on new object incorrectly query db for null foreign keys"](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5215).